# R select spatial polygon with point inside

Tags: r, spatial

I have a shapeFile and a spatialPointsDataframe ... I would like to select all polygon where there is point(s) inside, and merge points information in shp@data

```
word<-readOGR(dsn="data/world/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp", layer="ne_110m_admin_0_countries")
xy<-cbind(geoloc$longitude,geoloc$latitude)
spxy<-SpatialPoints(xy)
spdfxy<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(spxy,geoloc)
spdfxy@data<-merge(spdfxy@data,data2000geo)

tps<-!is.na(over(spdfxy,word)) ##retourne the indexe of atribut of y renvois les atribut de word
```

But after that I don't know how select polygones. i have tried

```
vitiWord<-word[tps]
```

but it's doesn't work

for download exemple -> [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1822157/stack.zip)

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example ? it will help a lot

Comment: I didn't try but may word[tps, ] can work

Comment: no it doesn't work whit word[tps,]. tps is a logical vector and I'haven't a variable in table to do something like word[tps==TRUE]

Comment: In fact I would like to have an acces to a fonction like within in GIS for selected all polygon where there is points insisde

Comment: Well if you give a example with a polygon and some points (using data from a package or dropbox link) I promise to work on it (I'm sure other will help too), otherwise I don't have time right now to create a reproducible example. This is typical is StackOverflow if you want some help then "help" those willing to help by providing a example I can run on my computer.

Comment: Et voilà, 2 shapefiles, one whit word and other with points, I'would like to take data from points in polygons if the point is inside ... [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1822157/stack.zip)

Comment: I don't see it ? Please make sure your question is edited.

Comment: sorry I am not yet an expert with markwon and stackoverflow ... Any way, thank's for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'have find some thing... 
I don't realy know if it work because I would like to use ggplot after and it doesn't work well, but whit

```
jointure<-over(word,spdfxy) #over from sp library
word@data<-cbind(word@data,jointure)
```

You have all variable from point in the spatialDataFrame !!